# Select all submit buttons that have a certain function in their onclick event

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I want to programm a double-submit prevention with an overlay layer that is created by my function `setWaitLayer()`. How can I select with jQuery all submitbuttons, that have the function setWaitLayer in it, like

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="setWaitLayer("Please Wait");maybe_some_other_stuff()">
</form>
<form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="alert('this is not disabled')">
</form>
```

and change those onclick events that have setWaitLayer in it to:

```
onclick="alert('Form already sent'); return false"
```

Is there something like

```
$('input[onclick^="setWaitLayer"]').on('click',function(){
   alert('Form already sent');
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you work either with classes or data attributes to identify it?

```
<input type="submit" onclick="setWaitLayer("Please Wait");maybe_some_other_stuff()" class="wait_submit">
```

Then you can wait as follows

```
$('input[type="submit"].wait_submit').on('click',function(){
   alert('Form already sent');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: This is not the question. Then I would have to change the whole installation (=a lot of work). I want to select only by that function. In that php framework I administer there is everywhere only that function in the submitbuttons I want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Try like,

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(){
   alert('Form already sent');
   return false;
});
```

**Updated**

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" id="submitForm1" onclick="setWaitLayer('Please Wait');maybe_some_other_stuff()">
</form>
<form>
    <input type="submit" id="submitForm2" onclick="alert('this is not disabled')">
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#submitForm2').on('click',function(){
   alert('Form already sent');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: that would select all input fields

Comment: `$('input[type="submit"]')` only submit

Comment: That would be another aproach: select by class. But here I would like to select by onclick-event content. I added an example of what kind of solution I am looking for